# Storing values from for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I am looking to save the values from "roc_full_resolution" into a vector. Any ideas?

```
 for(i in 1:10) repeat {
CarefulR<- merge(data,reliable,by.x ="Response_ID" )
CarefullRespondents <- CarefulR %>% select(Response_ID,Category,Q17_1,Q17_2,Q17_3,Q17_4,Q17_5,Q17_6,Q17_7,Q17_8,Q17_9,Q17_10,Q17_11,Q17_12,Q17_13,Q17_14,Q17_15,Q17_16,Q17_17,Q17_18,Q17_19,Q17_20,Q17_21,Q17_22,Q17_23,Q17_24)
CarelessRespondents<- unreliable %>% select(Response_ID,Category,Q17_1,Q17_2,Q17_3,Q17_4,Q17_5,Q17_6,Q17_7,Q17_8,Q17_9,Q17_10,Q17_11,Q17_12,Q17_13,Q17_14,Q17_15,Q17_16,Q17_17,Q17_18,Q17_19,Q17_20,Q17_21,Q17_22,Q17_23,Q17_24)
CR2<- sample_n(CarelessRespondents, 146,replace = TRUE)
df <- rbind(CarefullRespondents,CR2)[-1]
simulation1_mahad <- mahad_raw <- mahad(df )
rounded_scores <- round(simulation1_mahad, digits=1)
roc_rounded <- roc(df$Category, rounded_scores)
roc_full_resolution <- roc(df$Category,rounded_scores)
print(roc_full_resolution)
break}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store values in a vector inside a for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741558/how-to-store-values-in-a-vector-inside-a-for-loop-in-r)

Comment: No it just gives me a blank vector

Comment: It would help if you gave a reproducible example of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the roc_full_resolution variable before the `for` loop, then `append` the results on each iteration. I would also move the setup outside the loop, and I don't think the `repeat` and `break` are needed in this situation.

```
CarefulR <- merge(data, reliable, by.x = "Response_ID")
CarefullRespondents <- CarefulR %>% select(Response_ID,Category,Q17_1,Q17_2,Q17_3,Q17_4,Q17_5,Q17_6,Q17_7,Q17_8,Q17_9,Q17_10,Q17_11,Q17_12,Q17_13,Q17_14,Q17_15,Q17_16,Q17_17,Q17_18,Q17_19,Q17_20,Q17_21,Q17_22,Q17_23,Q17_24)
CarelessRespondents <- unreliable %>% select(Response_ID,Category,Q17_1,Q17_2,Q17_3,Q17_4,Q17_5,Q17_6,Q17_7,Q17_8,Q17_9,Q17_10,Q17_11,Q17_12,Q17_13,Q17_14,Q17_15,Q17_16,Q17_17,Q17_18,Q17_19,Q17_20,Q17_21,Q17_22,Q17_23,Q17_24)
roc_full_resolution<-NULL
for(i in 1:10) {
    CR2 <- sample_n(CarelessRespondents, 146, replace = TRUE)
    df <- rbind(CarefullRespondents, CR2)[-1]
    simulation1_mahad <- mahad_raw <- mahad(df)
    rounded_scores <- round(simulation1_mahad, digits = 1)
    roc_rounded <- roc(df$Category, rounded_scores)
    roc_full_resolution <- append(roc_full_resolution, roc_rounded)
  }
print(roc_full_resolution)
```

Comment: Tried this and it produces a null vector

Comment: I can not troubleshoot without a reproducible example. The quickest way forward is for you to examine the output you do have.... Does `roc_rounded` have data? does `rounded_scores` have data? does `df` have data?